# Nil pointer dereference trying to copy pointer to pointer

Tags: pointers, go, memory, reference, pass-by-reference

I have the following piece of code working correctly:

```
type Type struct {
    p string
}

func foo() {
    t := Type { p: "hola" }
    bar(&t)
}

var bar = func(t *Type) {
    t.p = "chau"
}

func Test1() {
    var baz *Type
    bar = func(t *Type) {
        baz = t
    }
    foo()
    fmt.Println(baz.p)
}
```

Basically I'm mocking the bar function in order to know the parameter that the function `foo` is passing when it runs. Now, suppose that I want to extract the logic of the mocking function in another function, how should I do it? I tried the following but got an `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`:

```
func mockedBar(b** Type) func(*Type) {
    return func(t *Type) {
        *b = t
    }
}

func Test2() {
    var baz **Type
    bar = mockedBar(baz)
    foo()
    fmt.Println((**baz).p)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
var baz *Type
bar = mockedBar(&baz)
foo()
fmt.Println((*baz).p)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FpFCB9enSiQ

Comment: Hi @FooBarBazical welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a moment to check out the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

`var` means that you will allocate the following variable with the given type.

`var t Type` will allocate the full size of Type, 24 bytes, for example.

`var p *Type` will allocate only 4-8 bytes for the Pointer itself.

`var pp **Type` will allocate the same 4-8 bytes because it's the same pointer but which points to another pointer.

To solve that puzzle you have to:

```golang
// allocate an object and take a pointer to it
p := &Type{}
/*
it's also equivalent of:

var t Type
p := &t 
*/

// take a pointer to pointer
pp := &p
```